# Not able to access container view's tableview controller elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have  a view controller (vc1) which has a container view and below that it has a save button . Container view is embed segued to tableview controller(tvc1) having static cells . Each cell has labels and textfields. 
I am trying to get the contents of textfields in tvc1 in vc1 . 
I tried two methods :

Preparefor segue in vc1:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"prepare for segue called in settings view controller.");
    NSString * segueName = segue.identifier;
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"embedseguesettings"]) {
        NSLog(@"embed segue called ");
        settingsTableViewController *tvc1 = (settingsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc1.surlTextField.text = @"i got u ";        
    }
}
```

i am getting print for "embed segue called ", but the textfield in tvc1 is not updated with my text "i got u". Have i got the tvc1 object properly ?

Instantiate tvc1  in vc1:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    settingsTableViewController *tvc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsTableView"];
    NSLog(@"surl textfeild = %@",tvc1.surlTextField.text);
}
```

But i always get null as output. i type some text to surl textfield an press save . i always get null.

settingsTableViewController is the container view's table view controller and i have only set the no of sections and no of rows in that class. Do i need to dequeue cells , i should not be ? , its a static tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the textField value in tvc1 before the view has loaded.

You should add a property in tvc1…

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* someText;
```

then in your `prepareForSegue` method, assign to `someText` and also **keep a reference to tvc1**

```
if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"embedseguesettings"]) {
    settingsTableViewController *tvc1 = (settingsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    tvc1.someText = @"i got u ";   
    self.tvc1 = tvc1     
}
```

and in your tvc1 `viewDidLoad`

```
tvc1.surlTextField.text = self.someText
```

Then in your save method:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    // Don't instantiate a new tvc1
    NSLog(@"surl textfeild = %@",self.tvc1.someText);
}
```

Comment: perfect . Thanks a lot.

Comment: But for the second method , when i am trying to instantiate tvc1 through storyboard , at this time tvc1 is already showing and is been loaded. why it does not show the text field ?

Comment: When you instantiate the view controller, it creates a new instance of that class - not the one you updated

Answer (score 1):

As per `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` flow its still not allocated it outlets so...

The `UIViewController` isn't loaded at that moment.
You need to set `@property` values and access that in the `viewDidLoad()` method 
and setup your textFiled text accordingly.